# Are all DLLs stored on an HDD or SSD disk in an Azure Function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, cold-start

I'm running a function app in consumption mode and would like to know if all the assemblies packaged in an app are stored on an HDD or SSD? I'm seeing bad cold start times. If HDDs are being used, is there a way to upgrade to SSDs (without having to upgrade to a Premium plan)?

Comment: Azure app service is paas, you should be based on the virtual concept of service plan, not the virtual machine behind it. Even if the virtual machine has a better storage disk, it will only give you the corresponding service according to the service plan's commitment. If the service plan you choose does not provide SSD persistent storage, then even if the virtual machine behind the service plan has SSD It will not be allocated for you to persistently store files like dll.

Comment: Hi, do you have any other doubts?

Comment: No. Thanks for your help. Does Microsoft have any plans to offer SSDs for Function apps in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Function is based on the App Service Sandbox. If you deploy it to azure, it will be deployed to a physical machine for storage and processing according to the virtual concept of service plan. If you use a Service Plan that Azure does not promise to give SSD durable storage, then your files will not be durable stored on the SSD. (Even if there is an SSD disk on the physical machine assigned to you, it will definitely not give you the SSD for durable storage.)

For example, your function app is based on a service plan, which requires Azure to allocate two virtual machines. Under these circumstances, no matter whether the actual physical machine has SSD or not, as long as the service plan you choose does not support SSD durable storage, then azure will not allocate your compiled files to the SSD disk for you to durable store(such as dll).

If you want to use SSDs for persistent storage, then you should choose a service plan that promises to provide persistent storage SSDs. Because the azure function is deployed to the machine based on the service plan.

Comment: I understand all of that, but I need to know if there is a way to use SSDs with Azure Functions. Does the consumption plan only provide HDDs? What about the premium plan?

Comment: @user246392 If you need to use SSD for durable storage, please select PremiumV2 pricing tier. The service plan of this layer is divided into three specifications: Small (one CPU core, 3.5 GiB of memory), Medium (two CPU cores, 7 GiB of memory), Large (four CPU cores, 14 GiB of memory). You can choose according to your needs. The consumption plan is based on A-series virtual machines and does not provide SSD durable storage.

Comment: @user246392 Please note that the premium plan I am talking about is not the premium plan in the function document, but the premium plan in the app service plan. The premium plan in the hosting plan option of the function app also does not provide SSD durable storage.